# Use of Parceler with Kotlin data class with constructor for serialization

Tags: parcelable, kotlin, parceler

Is there a way to use [Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler) with Kotlin data classes and constructor for serialization without using `@ParcelProperty` annotation for each field?

If I try and use library like this:

```
@Parcel
data class Valve @ParcelConstructor constructor(val size: Int)
```

I get `Error:Parceler: No corresponding property found for constructor parameter arg0`. But if I add `@ParcelProperty("size")` it works just fine.
Why is that?

**Update**:
There are other another way to use this library.
I could just remove `@ParcelConstructor` annotation, but then I will get error
`Error:Parceler: No @ParcelConstructor annotated constructor and no default empty bean constructor found.`
I think (haven't tested it) I also could make all constructor parameters optional and add `@JvmOverloads` but that has a side effect that I have to check all properties of the class if they are null or not.

**Update 2**:
This is what worked for me:

```
@Parcel
data class Valve(val size: Int? = null)
```

In short generated Java class must have default empty constructor. One way to achieve that is to do as above - all variables should have default values.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the docs, Parceler by default works with public fields. But a usual Kotlin `data class` (as in your example) is rather a "traditional getter/setter bean", since every Kotlin property is represented by a private field and a getter/[setter].

TL; DR: I think this will work:

```
@Parcel(Serialization.BEAN)
data class Valve(val size: Int = 10)
```

Note the default value, it allows Kotlin to automatically generate an additional empty constructor, which is required by the Java Been specification.

Another way would be to mark the constructor that we already have:

```
@Parcel(Serialization.BEAN)
data class Driver @ParcelConstructor constructor(val name: String)
```

The specific document: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler#gettersetter-serialization

Comment: That wouldn't work since it requires default empty bean constructor. I'll update my question.

Comment: to have an empty constructor you can provide a  default value to `size`. Updated

Comment: or annotate the primary constructor with `@ParcelConstructor` just as in your example

Comment: btw, for having an empty constructor you should not need `@JvmOverloads`, what I said above should be sufficient. Let me know when you try it out

Comment: @voddan how did you compiled parceler to kotlin? im not being able to make Parcel to work in Kotlin.

Comment: @FábioCarballo I never did. For my project (a server) I use Jackson (kotlin module). I answered because the issue with Parcel was of the same nature that the one I solver with Jackson, and the syntax I looked up in the docs.

Comment: You may ask @MartynasJurkus, he made it work (obviously). For that you may want to post the compilation error you are getting. Or create a separate question, since chances are you problem is build-related, not kotlin-related.

Comment: @FábioCarballo see my updated question on how I got it working based on this answer

Comment: Using this approach I can get everything to compile, but it doesn't work, because the generated `Value$$Parcelable` class doesn't contain any code to write/read `size`. Am I missing something, has this been proved to work?

Comment: also worth noting in some scenarios `val` should be `var` if the value is expected to change

Answer (score 10):

I know this question already has an answer, but for future viewers who are also struggling to get Parceler to work with kotlin data objects, I wrote a new annotation processor to generate the Parcelable boilerplate for Kotlin data classes. It's designed to massively reduce the boilerplate code in making your data classes Parcelable:

https://github.com/grandstaish/paperparcel

**Usage:**

Annotate your data class with `@PaperParcel`, implement `PaperParcelable`, and add a JVM static instance of the generated `CREATOR` e.g.:

```
@PaperParcel
data class Example(
  val test: Int,
  ...
) : PaperParcelable {
  companion object {
    @JvmField val CREATOR = PaperParcelExample.CREATOR
  }
}
```

Now your data class is `Parcelable` and can be passed directly to a `Bundle` or `Intent`

**Edit:** Update with latest API

Answer (score 5):

Just add the default constructor:

```
@Parcel
data class Valve(val size: Int) {
    constructor() : this(0)
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? I had the same issue and fixed it exactly this way.

Comment: This works for me. BTW you need to use kapt:

`compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'`
`kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'`

Comment: Specifying `size` with a default value (as mentioned above) should fulfill the need for the parameterless constructor, no?

Answer (score 4):

if you use Kotlin 1.1.4 or above it's easier to use @Parcelize annotation

For doing this first add this to **build.gradle**

```
android {
    //other codes

    //for using latest experimental build of Android Extensions
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}
```

Then change your class like this

```
@Parcelize
data class Valve(val size: Int? = null) : Parcelable
```